# Projection out of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let A,B be orthogonal matrices of order $n \geq 2 $. $\det A = 1, \det
>  B = -1$.
>
> There exist $a \in [0,1]$ such that  $aA + (1-a)B$ is projection.

I know that the claim above is false. I fail to come up with a counterexample, so I decided to use $PP = P$ property of projection with hope to run into some contradiction.

$$a^2A^2 + a(1-a)(AB + BA) + (1-a)^2B^2 = aA + (1-a)B$$

And here I stuck. Could you help me: how can I utilize the fact that A,B are orthogonal.

Comment: By a *projection*, do you mean an *orthogonal projection* or a general *oblique projection*?

Comment: A general projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not necessarily false if $P$ was allowed to be an orthogonal projection. For a trivial example, take $A=I$  and $a=1$. The identity matrix is certainly a projection.

The claim is, however, false if $P$ is assumed to be a "strictly" nonorthogonal projection. We know that a projection $P$ is nonorthogonal if and only if $\|P\|_2>1$, see, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1113478/90996). However, for any $x$, 
$$
\|[aA+(1-a)]x\|_2\leq a\|Ax\|_2+(1-a)\|Bx\|_2=a\|x\|_2+(1-a)\|x\|_2=\|x\|_2,
$$
which implies that $\|aA+(1-a)B\|_2\leq 1$.

Comment: On a second thought, I agree with you that the claim is correct. It must be a misprint in my answers. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @AvaSkovko What do you mean? $aA+(1-a)B$ cannot be a nonorthogonal projection since otherwise we might get a contradiction. It might, however, be an orthogonal projection unless there would be some additional hypotheses on $A$ and $B$ or possibly $a$.