# $A^2=A $ prove $A$ is hermite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ satisfying $A^2=A$ , for every $n\times 1$ vector $x$ we have $|Ax|\le|x|$ where $| |$ denotes the usual norm of vector , prove $A$ is a hermite matrix.

Comment: your thoughts/attempts? You are reputed enough to know that questions without personal attempt shown are discouraged here!

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1113520/81360)

Comment: @JessePFrancis well , I don't know how the inequality condition show any information of A , and so I really don't have any thoughts , can you help me